# AppEngine in Go not returning Content-Length from urlfetch.Head

Tags: google-app-engine, http, go

I am trying to perform a `HEAD` request to a URL so I can get the `Content-Length` header and then do Range requests.

However I found out AppEngine doesn't return the `Content-Length` header when doing `urlfetch.Head`. The documentation is explicit about it for responses, but not for requests.

```
Etag:["359670651"]
Expires:[Thu, 16 Oct 2014 20:41:52 GMT]
Server:[ECS (mdw/1275)]
X-Cache:[HIT]
X-Ec-Custom-Error:[1]
X-Google-Cache-Control:[remote-fetch]
Accept-Ranges:[bytes]
Cache-Control:[max-age=604800]
Content-Type:[text/html]
Date:[Thu, 09 Oct 2014 20:41:52 GMT]
Last-Modified:[Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT]
```

It works correctly when using `net/http` of the Go library.

```
Last-Modified:[Fri, 09 Aug 2013 23:54:35 GMT]
Server:[ECS (iad/182A)]
Content-Length:[1270]
Accept-Ranges:[bytes]
Cache-Control:[max-age=604800]
Date:[Thu, 09 Oct 2014 20:38:01 GMT]
X-Cache:[HIT]
X-Ec-Custom-Error:[1]
Content-Type:[text/html]
Etag:["359670651"]
Expires:[Thu, 16 Oct 2014 20:38:01 GMT]
```

Is there any solution to this? A `HEAD` request without the `Content-Length` is kind of useless in my opinion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reasons beyond my understanding, App Engine does not include the content length in the [response Header](http://godoc.org/net/http#Response.Header) for any request method.

Comment: That is exactly what I was searching for, the difference of behaviour between vanilla Go and AppEngine Go confused me. Thanks.